# First time using Virtualbox, first time installing Lubuntu, stuck at Partitions page

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, lubuntu

I've spent the last 48 hours trying to figure out how to install Lubuntu 21.10 as the guest OS in Virtualbox on my Windows 10 laptop. Unfortunately, as I was using the wizard, I had to close it then found out there is no way to return to it and no instructions aside from using the wizard, at least none that don't assume you're an expert.
Now I've gotten to the point where I am using the Lubuntu installer and I am stuck on the Partitions page. [image]
The blue drop-down has only that one option, 10 GB I set up earlier in the process. (Not dynamic if that matters.)
I know the Lubuntu OS doesn't know it's in a VM but I'm afraid to click Erase Disk. Can it erase my whole laptop?
I would choose Manual partitioning and I've partitioned my old computers before, but I want the whole 10GB for Lubuntu. I'm afraid to click it unless it's what I need to do because I may not be able to go back, especially after the mess I created before when I clicked out of the wizard.
On Lubuntu's help page I only see instructions if I were installing it to be the only OS on my computer.
What should I do here? I don't want to erase my Windows 10.

Add: I clicked the radio button for Erase Disk without clicking Next, and the screen changed to this: [image]

Comment: No, "erase disk" refers ONLY to the virtual drive previously created within Virtualbox. As usual, the installer can only see and use the virtualized hardware.

Comment: Please correct the release details; Ubuntu main releases are *year.month* in format; and there is no 0 month.  Do you mean 21.04 (ie. 2021-April release) or 21.10 (ie. 2021-October release).

Comment: Did you try the Lubuntu manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html   (the link for the *latest* stable release which is Lubuntu 21.10 currently)

Comment: FYI:  I believe @Nmath has addressed your concern; ie. the disk referred to by the Lbuntu installer (`calamares`) is a *virtual* one provided by your Virtualbox, and not you real system disk (which is under your HOST OS control; ie. windows 10). Leave the *boot loader* to the defaults; it's the disk (sda) provided by your virtualbox (not your real hardware).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Erase Disk" refers to the virtual hard drive you set up in VirtualBox.

You can safely use this option.  The VM container is unable to wipe the host OS hard drive.

Comment: Thank you. I chose the default for Master Boot Record and the installation is done now. Whew.